# Fragment replacement not working in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am working on an application which is having a tab at bottom,Each tab click will replace current fragment,I have tried to replace a fragment but my app crashed without any error,Can anybody help me to solve it?my code for replacing fragment is as below,

```
public class Tab5Container extends BaseContainerFragment {

     private boolean IsViewInited;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_framelayout, null);
     }
         @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (!IsViewInited) {
       IsViewInited = true;
       initView();
      }
     }
         private void initView() {
          replaceFragment(new NewProfileFragment(), false);
     }
    }
```

**basefragment**

```
public class BaseContainerFragment extends Fragment {

     public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
          FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          if (addToBackStack) {
             transaction.addToBackStack(null);
          }

          transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, fragment);
          transaction.commit();
          getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
         }

         public boolean popFragment() {
          Log.e("Ritesh", "pop fragment: " + getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
          boolean isPop = false;
          if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
           isPop = true;
           getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
          }
          return isPop;
         }


}
```

Please help me i wasted 1 day for this..:(

Comment: Is there any warning log?

Comment: @Krish - No brother,it just comes black screen and then come to back page.

Comment: @krish - it give me below warning.`Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
05-02 01:19:03.182    1964-1964/com.company.stush E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
05-02 01:19:03.202    1964-1964/com.company.stush E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
05-02 01:19:03.202    1964-1964/com.company.stush E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192`